# Is it dangerous to sync my data with my personal server through unencrypted http?

Tags: tls, http, man-in-the-middle

Since Apple force iPhone users to use iCloud to sync contacts & calendar, I moved to a local ownCloud instance that works well. However, it would be more convenient if I could sync everywhere and not only when my local webserver is started (and thus I'm near my laptop), so I'm thinking of a simple VPS with ownCloud installed, but I can't afford an SSL certificate.

Therefore I guess my contacts & calendars would sync in "clear", am I right ?
Easier to intercept (if so) than a local sync ?

It may be evident but I need certitude.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are worried about.  Transmitting it unsecured means someone could alter it in transit or monitor the connection and make off with your data.  Further, they could access your OwnCloud credentials and take, remove or alter data on your OwnCloud account.  If you are just using it in a read only manner, you are a little better off, but still open to manipulation before it gets to you.  This probably isn't a significant risk for most people, but it is a risk that can be easily mitigated.

You can use a self-signed SSL certificate for this and add your signing certificate as trusted (or simply accept the untrusted connection).  This will still provide encryption for your connection but won't cost you anything.  You only have to pay to get an SSL certificate that is verified by a certificate authority.

If you do decide you want a trusted certificate, they are also pretty cheap.  I get mine from StartSSL for under $60 for a 2 year SSL cert.  I actually use that cert with my OwnCloud instance and it works great.